# Should we bother about Manglik in marriage?

Tags: belief, history, practice, marriage, astrology

I find this is quite a confusing situation in India during marriage proposals. When a girl is manglik people don't proceed to marriage. I just wanted understand the effects of this manglik thing.

In some astrology apps i find manglik got a category too like High,Medium and Low
How this affects? Does manglik marriages don't sustain or how it goes?

Someone please explain me about this.

Comment: Mangala Dosha is one of the numerous aspects seen in a horoscope. Such things should not be seen in isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mangal Dosha is an astrological combination that occurs if Mars (Mangal Grha) is present in the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 7th, 8th, or 12th house of the ascendant chart. A person born in the presence of this condition is termed a manglik.

Some people believe that manglik cause discomfort and tension in relationship, leading to severe disharmony among the spouses and eventually to other bigger problems.

However, there are many easy solutions to overcome that. There is  an astrological solution to nullify the bad luck of being Manglik. You just need to do a symbolic marriage to a peepal tree, before the main marriage.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.