# What are the ill-effects of having Mangalik Dosha?

Tags: astrology

What are the ill-effects of having Mangalik Dosha in one's Rashi and Lagna?

Please cite answers from actual Vedic Jyotisha and not pop culture beliefs.

Comment: Related: [what does being maanglik means. Is it bad or good?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10048/277)

Comment: "pop culture beliefs" lol