# Can a person whose manglik dosha was cancelled still marry a manglik person

Tags: astrology, kundali, vedic

Suppose a person has mangal in 1st house in kundali, so has mangal dosha. But also there is saturn in 4th house, which will cancel the mangal dosha.

It is said that a mangalik person can marry a mangalik person.

But can a mangalik person whose mangal dosha was nullified still marry a mangalik person ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we bother about Manglik in marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-bother-about-manglik-in-marriage)

Comment: AFAIK, Mangal dosha is nullified when a 'shubha graha' or 'shubha graha' aspects mars and not 'krura graha or 'paapa graha'. Saturn being a Paapa graha won't cancel mangal dosha. Moreover, you need to see the nakshatra of Mars. If it's in own nakshatra, then mangal dosha is very high.

Comment: By the way, for your main question, whether mangal dosha gets less or more or gets cancel, in any case, the person is still Maanglik. So that person has to still marry a Maanglik person.